# Error: Unexpected data type using sparklyr package

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error when creating sparklyr data tables.

As a result, I'm not able to see the spark data tables in the spark window in Rstudio.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 Error: Unexpected data type
```

[image]

Comment: Which `sparklyr` version are you using? It works for me with `sparklyr_0.5.1`

Comment: I'm using the dev version devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr") how could I specify an earlier dev version? The reason I'm using the dve version is because with the CRAN version I get the following error:   Error : object 'sql_build' not found whilst loading namespace 'sparklyr'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sparklyr’

Comment: I think you can do it with `install_version`. Here you can find a guide about it https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks Jaime!

Comment: Jaime-- I was able to fix it by first intalling sparklyr and then dplyr. Doing it the other way around causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad it finally worked out that way.